# ASP.NET SharePoint web part: Showing subsites calender events in root site calender

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, calendar, web-parts

I have for testing purposes a sitecollection called BigBroSite. Under the root site i have three subsites called Support, Development and Marketing. On each of the subsites I have a calender app with events in it. What I want do do is to find all the events in all the subsite calenders and show them in the root calander.

I have SharePoint 2013, VS 2017, Working with a SharePoint 2013 solution and added a visual web part to the project.

The Code I got so far is:

```
  protected void calender()
    {


        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;

        foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
        {
            foreach (SPList cal in web.Lists)
            {
                if (cal.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Events)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItemCollection activity in cal.Items)
                    {



                    }

                }


            }
        }
    }
```

i have searched the web and found alot of tutorials using database. I dont get how to translate that to my problem. Should I have a

> SPListItemCollection

to transfer event data to the calander proprties. I also dont know wich methods to call from the calander that can receive the SPListItemCollection. What i have gathered so far is that I should use

```
 protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

to show the event I gathered from the subsites. Feel free to point me in the right direction if you think I am on the wrong path.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Any code to get this done! actually you need to config your Calenders

1- you need to create a "new Calendar"

[image]

2- in Calender Overlay Settings you'll put your subsite URL

[image]

when you add Event into your subsite Calendar then it'll show on Root Calendar

[image]

Comment: Thanx. For the suggestion. I Will definitely try it out. But I also want to learn how to do it by code.

Comment: It's unfortunately not the answer to the question above. I would like to reach the same goal but with my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Melad's answer is the way to go unless you have a specific other use case. In which case you still don't want to build it custom, you want to use a Content Search Web Part with a custom Display Template. If you're just trying to learn how to interact with sharepoint lists using C# respond back and we can look at answering that question (though you're on the wrong track for performance, use SPSiteDataQuery or SPQuery and never go to SPList.Items, use SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)).